# What is difference between myvariable.subproperty?.value and myvariable.subproperty!.value?

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the difference between: `myvariable.subproperty?.value` and `myvariable.subproperty!.value`
It seems both execute if subproperty is null, delivering a null value.  I know what assertion operators mean in general, just not sure what it means when you chain call properties like this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object?.value` is JavaScript syntax, and will:

- If `object` is null or undefined, evaluate to `undefined`
- Otherwise, will access the `value` property on the object

`object!.value` is TypeScript syntax, and will:

- Assert to the TypeScript compiler that `object` is neither null nor undefined
- Unconditionally attempt to access the `value` property on the object

If there's a chance that the object is null or undefined, `?.` is the right approach, because if you use `!`, a runtime error could result. (Only use `!` when you're absolutely certain that the expression on the left will always exist, and you need to indicate that to the TypeScript compiler)